# Are tempdb allocations released after transaction is commited?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, tempdb, sp-whoisactive

In addition to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/291776/6171) I am again wondering if the code in a transaction and loop release the *tempdb* allocations. For the template below:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;


WHILE EXISTS(....)
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY;
            
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        --

            UPDATE TOP(X) ...

        --

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;


    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN;
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;

        THROW;

    END CATCH;


    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

END;
```

In *sp_whoisactive* I can see millions of *tempdb* allocations. The question is can these allocations cause *tempdb* spill or they are summarized and the allocations are release after each transaction commit?

Comment: You should look at the `tempdb_current` column in the output to figure this out.